# Coldfusion 9 & IIS7 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I'm currently researching how to implement URL Rewriting and was wondering if someone could help shed some light.

Our current url structure is the following..

http://example.com/products.cfm?id=1234

http://example.com/recipes.cfm?id=6789

I would like to configure IIS so that URLs can be rewritten to the following (or similar)

http://example.com/products/1234/product-title-here

http://example.com/recipes/6789/yummy-recipe-ever

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Probably better suited for ServerFault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through [this walk through](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). The example comes close to what you want (replaced aspx with cfm).

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.cfm?id={R:1}&title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into Coldbox there is a rewrite.ini and IS7 web.config included 
http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/URLMappings.cfm

The Coldbox blog shared this link
http://blog.coldbox.org/blog/coldbox-and-url-rewrites-with-iis-7

Comment: Use that web.config as a guide to configure the pattern you need.